# Getting row samples from PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a data table with timestamp and some data columns. The rows are inserted in arbitrary time intervals, i.e. the timestamp difference of consecutive rows is not stable but ranges from several seconds to several hours.

I need to select one row per time interval of constant length, if there is any.

**Example**

To get the time intervals for selection, I have a function that generates table of time intervals, for example:

```
start_time              end_time
'2021-05-31 10:00:00'   '2021-05-31 10:10:00'
'2021-05-31 10:10:00'   '2021-05-31 10:20:00'
'2021-05-31 10:20:00'   '2021-05-31 10:30:00'
```

Then for this source data:

```
timestamp                data
'2021-05-31 10:01:00'    1
'2021-05-31 10:02:00'    2
'2021-05-31 10:05:00'    3
'2021-05-31 10:21:00'    4
```

I require result:

```
timestamp                data
'2021-05-31 10:01:00'    1
'2021-05-31 10:21:00'    4
```

- the first row out of three is selected for the first interval
- no row is selected for the second interval
- the first and only possible row is selected for the third interval

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lateral join to pick one row per interval:

```
select *
from get_intervals() i
cross join lateral
(
  select *
  from my_table t
  where t.timestamp >= i.start_time and t.timestamp < i.end_time
  order by t.timestamp -- or by something random?
  fetch first row only
) d;
```

(A lateral join is the first thing that comes to mind. To join all rows first and then use `DISTINCT ON` instead, could lead to a large intermediate result, so I would prefer the lateral join over that approach.)

Comment: @Pavel Bazika: Thank you for the edit. I often forget the alias for the derived table, because I'm working with Oracle where it is not mandatory. And yes, I missed the `ON` clause; I have changed the inner join to a cross join now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to join your table with the time interval, order by the interval and get a `DISTINCT ON (start_time,end_time)`. The example below creates the time intervals and joins them with table `t`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (start_time,end_time) tm, data
FROM t 
JOIN (SELECT 
       to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from tm) / 600 )) * 600) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS start_time,
       to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from tm) / 600 )) * 600) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' + interval '10 minutes' AS end_time
      FROM t) j ON tm BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
ORDER BY start_time,end_time,tm;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=da70aa3866eefb45d9f84e3321cbfc79)

```
WITH t (tm,data) AS(
  VALUES ('2021-05-31 10:01:00'::timestamp,1),
         ('2021-05-31 10:02:00'::timestamp,2),
         ('2021-05-31 10:05:00'::timestamp,3),
         ('2021-05-31 10:21:00'::timestamp,4)
) 
SELECT DISTINCT ON (start_time,end_time) tm, data
FROM t 
JOIN (SELECT 
       to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from tm) / 600 )) * 600) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS start_time,
       to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from tm) / 600 )) * 600) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' + interval '10 minutes' AS end_time
      FROM t) j ON tm BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
ORDER BY start_time,end_time,tm;

---------------------+-----
 2021-05-31 10:01:00 |   1
 2021-05-31 10:21:00 |   4
(2 rows)
```